# d3js simple donut chart not drawing path

Tags: d3.js

So my four `<g>` element are inserted with class ".arc" as I asked but there is no path. Any idea what did I miss ?

```
function DonutChart(el) {
    var self = this;
    this.el = el;
    this.initChart();
}

DonutChart.prototype.initChart = function() {
    this.data = [
        {
            color: "#F57D28",
            taux: 25
        },
        {
            color: "FFB4E6",
            taux: 25
        },
        {
            color: "#50BE87",
            taux: 25
        },
        {   
            color: "#F57D28",
            taux: 25
        }
    ];


    var self = this;
    this.margin = {
        top: 5,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 5,
        left: 0
    }
    this.width = $(this.el).width() - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = $(this.el).height() - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
    this.radius = Math.min(this.width,this.height)/2;

    var visWidth = $(this.el).width();
    var visHeight = $(this.el).height();

    this.svg = d3.select(this.el)
        .append('svg')
        .attr("class", 'DonutChart')
        .attr("width", visWidth)
        .attr("height", visHeight)
        .append('g')
        .attr('class','DonutChartLayer')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + visWidth/2 + ',' + visHeight/2 + ')');

    this.arc = d3.arc()
        .outerRadius(this.radius)
        .innerRadius(20);

   this.draw();

}

DonutChart.prototype.draw = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.pie = d3.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return console.log(d.taux); d.taux; });

    this.g = self.svg.selectAll('.arc')
        .data(self.pie(self.data));

    this.g.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

    this.g.append("path")
        .attr("d", self.arc)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return d.data.color;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a <strike>couple of</strike> mistake. <strike>`d3.arc()` is not a function, `arc` is part of `d3.svg`; also `pie` is part of `d3.layout`</strike> (with thanks to Gerardo Furtado, Apparently in d3 v4 api has flattened).

And the main error is in `value` function of pie chart which should be:

```
this.pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.taux; });
```

```js
function DonutChart(el) {
    var self = this;
    this.el = el;
    this.initChart();
}

DonutChart.prototype.initChart = function() {
    this.data = [
        {
            color: "#F57D28",
            taux: 25
        },
        {
            color: "FFB4E6",
            taux: 25
        },
        {
            color: "#50BE87",
            taux: 25
        },
        {
            color: "#F57D28",
            taux: 25
        }
    ];



  this.margin = {
        top: 5,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 5,
        left: 0
    };
    this.width = $(this.el).width() - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = $(this.el).height() - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
    this.radius = Math.min(this.width,this.height)/2;

    var visWidth = $(this.el).width();
    var visHeight = $(this.el).height();

    this.svg = d3.select(this.el)
        .append('svg')
        .attr("class", 'DonutChart')
        .attr("width", visWidth)
        .attr("height", visHeight)
        .append('g')
        .attr('class','DonutChartLayer')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + visWidth/2 + ',' + visHeight/2 + ')');

    this.arc = d3.arc()
        .outerRadius(this.radius)
        .innerRadius(20);

   this.draw();

};

DonutChart.prototype.draw = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.pie = d3.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) {
          return d.taux;
        });

    this.g = self.svg.selectAll('.arc')
        .data(self.pie(self.data));

    this.g.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

    this.g.append("path")
        .attr("d", self.arc)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return d.data.color;
        });


};

var el = document.getElementById('chart-container');
var chart = new DonutChart(el);
chart.draw();
```

```css
#chart-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart-container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `d3.arc()` and `d3.pie()` are the correct function names in D3 v4.x

Answer (score 1):

The only wrong part in your code is this:

```
.value(function(d) { return console.log(d.taux); d.taux; });
```

Which should be:

```
.value(function(d) { return d.taux; });
```

What happens is this: the `return` stops at the semicolon. So, it's returning the `console.log`. If you want to console.log something, do it *before* the return:

```
.value(function(d) { console.log(d.taux); return d.taux; });
```

Here is your working code:

```js
function DonutChart(el) {
    var self = this;
    this.el = el;
    this.initChart();
}

DonutChart.prototype.initChart = function() {
    this.data = [
        {
            color: "#F57D28",
            taux: 25
        },
        {
            color: "FFB4E6",
            taux: 25
        },
        {
            color: "#50BE87",
            taux: 25
        },
        {   
            color: "#F57D28",
            taux: 25
        }
    ];


    var self = this;
    this.margin = {
        top: 5,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 5,
        left: 0
    }
    this.width = $(this.el).width() - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = $(this.el).height() - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
    this.radius = Math.min(this.width,this.height)/2;

    var visWidth = $(this.el).width();
    var visHeight = $(this.el).height();

    this.svg = d3.select(this.el)
        .append('svg')
        .attr("class", 'DonutChart')
        .attr("width", visWidth)
        .attr("height", visHeight)
        .append('g')
        .attr('class','DonutChartLayer')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + visWidth/2 + ',' + visHeight/2 + ')');

    this.arc = d3.arc()
        .outerRadius(this.radius)
        .innerRadius(20);

   this.draw();

}

DonutChart.prototype.draw = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.pie = d3.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d.taux; });

    this.g = self.svg.selectAll('.arc')
        .data(self.pie(self.data));

    this.g.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

    this.g.append("path")
        .attr("d", self.arc)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return d.data.color;
        });


}

var el = document.getElementById('chart');
new DonutChart(el).draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="chart" style="width:300px; height:300px;"></div>
```